# iOS UDP socket "sendto" can't send immediately one by one

Tags: c++, ios, udp, rtp

I found that the  behavior of iOS socket "sendto" interface was different from android or linux kernel. When we call "sendto",we start wireshark capture at the same time . But we can't find the  capture data immediately. We make a test that we continuously sending 332 bytes by "sendto"  per 40ms interval.And we found that all data packets was send to the network in a short central time instead of a 40MS(or above) intervals. We doubt that the ios kernal made some change for udp.Also it may calls audio delay about 900-1000ms.

I have test in iphone 5s & iphone 6,iOS 10 or 11 by demo use "sendto" api

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int sSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);


struct sockaddr_in localAddr;
localAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    localAddr.sin_port = htons(1001);
    localAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if(bind(sSock, (struct sockaddr*)&localAddr, sizeof(localAddr)) < 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"bind error");
        return;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in sendAddr;
    sendAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sendAddr.sin_port = htons(21000);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "114.190.105.220", &sendAddr.sin_addr);
    char sendBuf[332] = {0};


    //unsigned char service_type = 0xe0 | IPTOS_LOWDELAY | IPTOS_RELIABILITY;
    int service_type = 0x10;
    int priority = 6;

    //if(setsockopt(sSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PRIORITY, &priority, sizeof(priority))<0)
    if(setsockopt(sSock,IPPROTO_IP,IP_TOS,(void*)(&service_type),sizeof(service_type)) < 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"setsockopt failed1,error[%s]",strerror(errno));
    }
   while(true)
   {
       sendto(sSock, sendBuf, sizeof(sendBuf), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sendAddr, sizeof(sendAddr));
       time_t timeNow;
       time(&timeNow);
       struct tm tmNow;
       struct timeval tvNow;
       localtime_r(&timeNow,&tmNow);
       gettimeofday(&tvNow, NULL);
       char sTime[256] = {0};
       snprintf(sTime, sizeof(sTime)-1, "%04d%02d%02d %02d%02d%02d.%d",tmNow.tm_year+1900,tmNow.tm_mon,tmNow.tm_mday,tmNow.tm_hour,tmNow.tm_min,tmNow.tm_sec,tvNow.tv_usec/1000);
       NSLog(@"[%s]interval 40ms send",sTime);
       usleep(40*1000);
   }
```

all data packets was send to the network in a short central time instead of a 40MS(or above) intervals.
all packets send at once，wireshark capture like this:

No.    Time                  Protocol

819    41.439392     H264

820    41.439617     H264

821    41.439819     H264

Comment: UDP stands for User Datagram Protocol. UDP provides an unreliable packet delivery system built on top of the IP protocol. Means there is no guarantee of  instant delivery at the other end

Comment: I capture in iphone side,not other end